# Get data from netcat, process it and send the response back to netcat

Tags: python, unix, netcat

I want to get input from netcat, process it with python script and send the processed data back to netcat.

i've tried this:

```
nc 10.0.0.2 4444 | python script.py
```

I get the input to the python script, but the output is going to the terminal
and not back to the netcat server. (connection is open and waiting for response)

my python script:

```
while True:
   line = sys.stdin.readline()
   sys.stdout.write("processed data")
```

Is there a way of doing it from a terminal or bash script?

Comment: You won't be able to do it this way as pipes (`|`) don't allow two way communication. You should probably look into a Python module called `subprocess`.

Comment: Could you just do the network communication directly with Python? The `socket` module does the same thing as netcat: open a connection to a particular address and port, and then send and receive data via that connection.

Comment: Use `ncat --sh-exec ...`  (That is `ncat` from `nmap`)

Answer (score 0):

You just need another redirect

```
nc 10.0.0.2 4444 | python script.py | nc
```

[xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) might be helpful for this.